# I cant install react-chat-engine with npm

Tags: python, reactjs, npm-install, react-chat-engine

> I tried installing react-chat-engine with npm but it throws follwing
> error
>
> **I guess its telling to install python but is it necessary ?**

```
bufferutil@4.0.6 install                            > node-gyp-build

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok timing reifyNod gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0                         gyp info using node@18.2.0 | android | arm64
gyp ERR! find Python \ reify:es5-ext: timing reifyNod
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON                                     gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be usedgyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,                                gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:395:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:407:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.112-perf+
gyp ERR! command "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node" "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /data/data/com.termux/files/home/chat_app/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v18.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok[##################] \ reify:es5-ext: t ming reifyNod
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /data/data/com.termux/files/home/chat_app/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-06-21T12_02_29_354Z-debug-0.log
```

> Is there any solution for this orI need to install python

Answer (score 0):

If npm Package or any of the dependencies that are about to be installed contains “native code” that needs to be compiled (eg c/c++ code) - npm uses `node-gyp` tool which is written in Python.  Thus, you need python to be installed.